# CMD prompt: %ERRORLEVEL% gets the correct output value from the second run

Tags: windows, command-line, exit-code

I have wolframscript installed on my Windows 10 PC.

Running the following commands on the command prompt get me

```
> where /q wolframscript & echo %ERRORLEVEL%
9009    <<< why didn't I get 0?

> where /q wolframscriptss & echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0       <<< why didn't I get 1?

> where /q wolframscriptss & echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1

> where /q wolframscriptss & echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1

> where /q wolframscript & echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1       <<< why didn't I get 0?

> where /q wolframscript & echo %ERRORLEVEL%
0
```

Considering my comments on the output, I would like to understand why I got an output different from what I expected.

My ultimate goal is to have a batch script
that checks the installation of a software program on my PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When CMD reads a command line or a command block,
it immediately expands any variables that it finds. 
So, for example, if you execute

```
where /q wolframscript & echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

when `ERRORLEVEL` is 9009 (from some previous activity),
CMD immediately translates it to

```
where /q wolframscript & echo 9009
```

and then executes that. 
You can demonstrate this easily:

```
C:\> set "VAR=red"

C:\> set "VAR=blue" & echo %VAR%
red
```

This general phenomenon is discussed in Microsoft’s [Environment
variable expansion occurs when the command is read](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060823-00/?p=29993) document,
which gives the more complex example:

```
set VAR=before
if "%VAR%" == "before" (
    set VAR=after
    if "%VAR%" == "after" @echo If you see this, it worked
)
```

where the message will not be displayed,
because the second `if` statement is expanded as

```
    if "before" == "after" @echo ...
```

---

I’m not sure exactly what you’re asking for,
but the simple fix here is simply to put the commands on separate lines:

```
C:\> where /q wolframscript
C:\> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not that knowledgeable to fully understand what you mean. However, is there a way to have a dynamic consistent output of checking the availability of installed program on my PC instead of this approach I followed in my question?

Comment: I actually run this command from latex file by `\immediate\write18{where\space wolframscript\space >null\space 2>null}%
  \immediate\write18{echo\space \@percentchar ERRORLEVEL\@percentchar\space >\space latexalpha2_check.tmp}%` However, sometimes I get this error `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.` I need to make sure wolframscript is installed before calling its commands.